# Why servicestack could not make model binding on json post request?

Tags: servicestack, model-binding

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/api/student",  
        data:'{"x":3,"y":2}',
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function (r, s) {
            debugger;
        },

        success: function(response){
            debugger;
        },

        contentType: "application/json" // !!!!!!!!!!!! The reason of problem. I could see Json on firebug. It was false-positive for my code !

    });
```

I've traced stream via Firebug. Firebug recognized and showed JSON object.

This code accessed RestServiceBase's OnPost method .But model binding did not work.
Do property names have to be exactly same on Json object and C# class?

Or am I missing something? (Yes, u are missing something!)

PS:I've changed url to  "/api/student/json/asynconeway" hopefully but then  I got 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to add

dataType: "application/json" property to ajax request!

Answer (score 4):

[ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) **does** model bind a JSON POST (as well as any of the supported Content-Types including x-www-form-urlencoded).

There are many examples in [ServiceStack.Examples](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/) that does this.

> This code accessed RestServiceBase's OnPost method .But model binding
>   did not work.

You have not shown what the DTO you're trying to bind to. But this JSON

```
{"x":3,"y":2}
```

Would map to a matching DTO, e.g:

```
public class Student { 
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

> Do property names have to be exactly same on Json object and C# class?

They have to match the names of-course, but **are not case-sensitive**, see above.

> PS:I've changed url to "/api/student/json/asynconeway" hopefully but
>   then I got 404 error

This is wrong. If you're trying to use an [automatic pre-defined route](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#predefinedroutes), the correct url is:

```
/api/json/asynconeway/student
```

Assuming your **Request DTO** is called `Student`.

Comment: Yes my requestDTO is Student.  Routes.Add<Student>("/student") in App.Host. I've also tested /api/json/asynconeway/student and got 404 error. Are "extra properties in json" problem?

Comment: That's not a problem, are you hosted at `/api`? what url does the `/metadata` page say? Otherwise you will need to post a gist of your Service + Web.Config

Comment: I've found my mistake. I 'm adding answer.

Comment: Right, but you should've edited your question with the solution and marked the answer that helped the most - As you're less likely to get future help by adding your own answers.

Comment: I've edited my question and I've added answer. But I can accept two days after (servicestack policy).

Comment: I very much doubt this is a servicestack policy :)

Comment: You understand the difference between ServiceStack and StackOverflow right?

Comment: That's because you're confused. ServiceStack != StackOverflow.

Comment: I got it mythz .. There is no confusion in my brain:) This is only  slip of the tongue or maybe "slip of the keyboard" .

Answer (score 0):

Here some code of mine:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/artist/delete",
                data: { id: itemId },
                success: function () {
                    $("div#" + itemId).fadeOut(function () { $(this).remove(); });
                }
            });
```

**EDIT:** Sorry I mistaken what you wanted there, so I will ask you a question, why are you sending json to server where you could make a function like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var artist = _db.Artists.Where(x => x.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();
            if (artist == null)
            {
                return Content("false");
            }
            else
            {
                _db.Artists.DeleteOnSubmit(artist);
                _db.SubmitChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Post");
            }
        }
```

**EDIT2:** and you have syntax error here `data:'{"x":3,"y":2)}',`.
**EDIT3:** Another syntax error

```
        }
        }
    });
```

At the end of code.

Comment: This is simplified sample. Normally I'm sending very big complex object to server.